# How to setup a REST service with a result as hhtprespon on Hadoop

Tags: rest, web-services, hbase, httpresponse, apache-nifi

actually I'm using a big data Environment where I ingest and process data with Apache Nifi. The results a saved in an HBase table and I want to access the stored data with Hive. Now I want to setup a REST service to read from the HBase table. Example

get http://localhost:50111/userid/42 --> http-response { "userid": 42, "name": "foobar" }

I thought that this is a standard problem with a existing solution, but it isn't. The problem is, that I can not send the result as http-response.

First I try it with Nifi and the webservice is working, but only with static content such as "200 OK", or "404 Not found". So I try it without Nifi. I read and everybody was saying, that WebHCat is the tool to go, because it is the REST API tool for Hive. Great! But... the same problem: I can execute queries over a REST service with WebHCat and Hive on HBase, but there is no option to retreive the result.

With my current knowledge there is no ready-made solution and I have to develop my own REST service. Right? Really?!

Do I have to develop my own REST service, or what is the best practice in this case? Nifi? Hiveserver2? Additionally I want to secure the REST service with Knox and Ranger.

I hope someone could help me and show me the right(!) way to go, because I don't want to make something new and special, if there is a better or best practice solution.

thanks
~n3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@n-3 - You have a number of options here.

Have a look at http://hortonworks.com/blog/hbase-via-hive-part-1/ for a basic hbase interaction with hive. You are also probably better off looking at Phoenix for this sort of usecase http://phoenix.apache.org/.

If you do go the direction of WebHCat and/or HiveServer2 you can already process access to both through Apache Knox with access control provided by Apache Ranger.

In addition, Apache HBase has a REST server of its own which you can also access through Apache Knox and protect with Apache Ranger. http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_rest

Hope this provides some help.